# Cannot disable Themes under "Manifest"

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I have Delphi 11.1 (fresh installed), Windows 10.
In "Project Options->Application->Manifest" I disable the Themes (uncheck "Enabled runtime themes") and save/close the dialog. But when I reopen the dialog, the Themes are again enabled.

Can anyone with Delphi 11 confirm this behavior?

_

PS: the checkbox works under:

- Delphi 10.4.2 + Win7
- Delphi 11 + Win 7.

Comment: This dialog has a long history of being obnoxious.

Comment: So, you think it is a Delphi bug? Then I guess I could set this manually via DPROJ or XML file...

Comment: Without having looked into the issue, I'd say that seems likely.

Comment: Does it happen only in one of your projects, or does it happen even in a brand new VCL app?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - Brand new VCL project.

Comment: @ServerOverflow Then you should [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I stopped years ago reporting bugs. They keep saying "cannot reproduce". And even if they can reproduce, they will fix it 8 years later. By that time, my Delphi license gets old, and I have to upgrade to a new license, only to find 3 new bugs to report for each bug fixed. No, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable that option in *All configurations - Windows 32-Bit platform* and if applicable also in *All configurations - Windows 64-Bit platform*. Then you can enable or disable it in the child configurations at your will.